# Как в React обратиться к элементу за пределами рута?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Весь проект построен на реакт-модулях. По сути, на странице есть много root-элементов в которые рендерятся компоненты. В итоге, часть страницы состоит из реакт компонентов, а часть из обычной верстки.

В такой "парадигме" возникла необходимость обратиться к элементу вне моего модуля, т.е. в соседний react-узел. Как это можно сделать?

В коде примерно так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>...</header>
  <main>
    ...

    <div id="root-1"></div> <!-- Реакт точка -->
  </main>

  <div id="root-2"></div> <!-- Вторая реакт точка -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться нативными методами javascript (Например, document.getQuerySelector)

Comment: _getQuerySelector_ - такого метода нет

Comment: Есть querySelectorAll или querySelector